# Java memory model: single thread and multi-core CPU

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, memory-barriers, memory-model

In a Java application, if accesses to an object's state happen on the same thread (in simplest case, in a single-threaded application), there is no need to synchronize to enforce visibility/consistency of changes, as per happens-before relationship specification:

"Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.

If we have two actions x and y, we write hb(x, y) to indicate that x happens-before y.

If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)."

But modern architectures are multi-core, so Java thread can potentially execute on any of them at any given time (unless this is not true and Java threads are pinned to specific cores?). So if that is teh case, if a thread writes to variable x, caches that in L1 cache or CPU register, and then starts running on another core, that previously accessed x and also cached it in a register, that value is incosistent... Is there some mechanism (implicit memory barrier) when thread is taken off a CPU?

Answer (score 7):

> can potentially execute on any of them at any given time

Tasks don't just spontaneously migrate between cores.  These things have to happen:

- the task is pre-empted on the core it was previously running on (marking it as waiting to run in the kernel's global task list)
- the kernel's task scheduler on another core sees that task waiting for a CPU and decided to run it.

(Scheduling is a distributed algorithm; each core is effectively running the kernel on that core very much like a multi-threaded process.  One core can't tell another core what to do, only put data in memory where the kernel running on that core can look at it.)

---

**This isn't a problem because:**

**Data caches (L1 and so on) are coherent across all cores that a thread could be scheduled on by an OS.**  [Myths Programmers Believe about CPU Caches](https://software.rajivprab.com/2018/04/29/myths-programmers-believe-about-cpu-caches/)

Or on hypothetical and unlikely hardware + OS + JVM that runs threads across cores with non-coherent shared memory, the OS would have to flush dirty private cache back to actual shared memory at some point after stopping the task on one core, before putting it in a global task queue where the task scheduler on another core could run it.

> Is there some mechanism (implicit memory barrier) when thread is taken off a CPU?

On a real-world system (coherent caches), the OS just has to make sure there's a full memory barrier that drains the store buffer on one core before another core can resume the task.

That barrier is not always implicit as part of something the OS was going to do anyway; **the OS kernel might need to explicitly include a barrier just for this**.  However, saving the register state and marking the task as runnable probably needed at least release stores, so another core that could restore this task's state would also see all user-space stores that task had done.

Still, I've heard of the possibility of breaking a single-threaded process by migrating between CPUs without sufficient barriers.  It is something to think about *for an OS*.  It's not at all Java specific; it's about how to not break a single thread running any arbitrary machine code.

---

**Only the registers are truly private**, and yes compilers will keep variables in registers.  I don't like the term "cached" for that; in asm registers are separate from memory.  Compilers can keep the *only* currently-valid copy of a variable in a register for the duration of a loop, and store it back afterwards.

**Every task has its own register state;** this is called the "architectural state" and is the context that's saved/restored by a context switch.

**Restarting execution of a thread on another core *means* restoring its saved register state from memory, ending by restoring its program-counter**.  i.e. jumping to the instruction it stopped at, restoring the program counter into the architectural program counter register.  e.g. RIP on x86-64. (64-bit version of the "Instruction Pointer" register)

Note that registers and (virtual) memory contents are the entire state of a user-space process (and open file descriptors and other kernel stuff associated with it).  But cache state is not.  Registers are not cache.  Cache is transparent to software (memory reordering happens because of the store buffer and CPU memory parallelism to hide cache misses, not because of cache, on most ISAs).  Registers are the asm equivalent of local variables.

---

**Compiler terminology: "caching"**

Hoisting a load out of a loop and keeping the value in a register is sometimes described as "caching" a value in a register, but that's just casual terminology that has you confused here.  The compiler-developer terminology for that is "Enregistration" of variables.

Or just "hoisting" a load or "sinking" a store out of a loop; normally you need to load a value into a register before you can use it for other things (at least on a RISC that doesn't have memory-source ALU instructions).  By hoisting a load of a loop-invariant value you only have to load once, ahead of the loop, and re-read the register multiple times.

Same for stores; if you know that no other threads are allowed to look at the memory location for a variable, only the final value needs to actually get stored with a store instruction.  Any other stores of other values would be "dead" if nothing can read them and we know there's a later store.  So you keep the variable in a register for the duration of the loop, then store once at the end.  This is called "sinking" a store, and is related to dead store elimination.

Comment: Or in short: multi core CPUs never took off if their introduction broke every existing software originally written for single core machines.

Answer (score 5):

Peter Cordes answered you from the implementation level, but it's worth mentioning the specificiation level:

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)."

That pretty much says it all right there. The Java language specification *guarantees* that if x comes before y at the source code level of your program, then x "happens before" y for purposes of determining memory visibility.

All of the stuff that Peter Cordes said is what guarantees `hb(x, y)`. If any JVM ever failed to do all of that stuff, then it would not be a valid implementation of Java.

Long story shortened: If your code only ever runs in a single thread, then you'll never have to worry about memory visibility.

Comment: Just expanded my answer a bit more.  In practice the JVM just depends on the OS to not break single-threaded code.  If you look at the whole OS + `java` process as implementing the Java virtual machine, your statement is accurate.  But if JVM = the `java` user-space process, then it's not special in this regard and can't fail at this; the cardinal rule of out-of-order execution (and OSes) is to preserve the illusion of a single thread running in program order.  So CPU migration is absolutely transparent to the JVM.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Agreed. I would expect any JVM that is designed to run on a typical, multi-processor desktop/server/mobile platform to rely heavily on the OS to provide support for threading and the memory model. I have no strong opinion about whether the answer to how a pure Java program behaves _should_ include details about what is implemented in the JRE source code and what is implemented in the OS source code. But sometimes I think it's _enough_ to say that from the Java programmer's point of view, it all happens "in the JVM."

Comment: Threading yes, to start threads on multiple cores.  But memory model no; to implement locks or `volatile` correctly (like C++ `std::atomic` with the default sequential-consistency semantics), the JVM itself has to JIT memory-barrier instructions like x86 `mfence` or ARM `dsb ish` to handle the case of multiple threads running simultaneously on multiple cores.  Not breaking a single thread is mostly up to the hardware but locking and lockless atomics are very much dependent on user-space executing the right instructions to implement any necessary memory ordering semantics.

Comment: True, but when you talk about `volatile` then you're straying from the OP's question because there is no need for `volatile` in code that only runs in a single thread.

Comment: Anyway, yes, it's enough to say that a JVM implement the Java memory model, but the only explicit question in this SO question is to explicitly ask how this is implemented.  The earlier parts of the question are just facts leading to an apparent contradiction or need for a memory barrier because of not understanding hardware and context switches.

Comment: You brought up the term "memory model" which is usually only associated with concurrency.  e.g. C++ didn't really *have* a memory model until C++11 formalized threading and introduced the C++ equivalent of `volatile`.  But sure, I guess the memory model still applies to a single thread, even if only to trivially say that everything is guaranteed to happen in program order.